# Server AMI images don't allow a user to login multiple times

Tags: command-line, server, amazon-ec2, byobu, cloud-init

When I log into twice to a new instance of Ubuntu server built for Amazon EC2, both windows will be exactly the same. Anything I type in one is replicated in the other.

I never dealt with this when I built the image myself. Does anyone know about this? I normally like to have a few putty windows open logged into the terminal of my servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch an instance in EC2 you have the option of supplying "user data" which is available to the instance at first boot (and later.)  Ubuntu consumes the user data with a program called cloud-init, which is incredibly powerful.

You can disable byobu using the user-friendly cloud-config feature of cloud-init.

To disable byobu all you have to do is supply this two-line user data:

```
#cloud-config
byobu_by_default: disable
```

Full details about cloud-init here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Cloud-config syntax, including all the other amazing things you can do with it, here: 
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-init-dev/cloud-init/trunk/view/head:/doc/examples/cloud-config.txt

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the pre-release Oneiric AMIs automatically run the screen command on ssh from a terminal which causes all of your ssh sessions to share a single screen.  You can learn how to use screen to disassociate what your terminals see, or...

You can disable this on a given instance by typing the command:

```
byobu-disable
```

which will log you out. The next ssh will work fine.

Hopefully, Oneiric will not include this behavior when it is released, but we're getting awful close to that date.

Note: This post includes statements that express my personal opinions. Other people have different opinions.

Answer (score 6):

As Eric said, you can disable byobu on the host with:

```
 $ byobu-disable
```

Once ssh'd in, you can disconnect from the current session but maintain a local shell with .

You can ssh in, and run bash instead of byobu:

```
 $ ssh -t <hostname> bash
```

And you can also make that permanent and affect all of your ssh sessions to Ubuntu/byobu hosts (where byobu > 4.0), by setting LC_BYOBU=0 in your local ~/.bashrc:

```
 $ echo "export LC_BYOBU=0" >> ~/.bashrc
 $ . ~/.bashrc
 $ ssh <hostname>
```

Comment: If you're using PuTTY, you can replicate the behavior of `ssh -t <hostname> bash` by setting the `Remote command` value to `bash` under 'Connection'->'SSH'.